# How to Move All Files From Drive A to Drive B? (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: server, partitioning, filemanager

Hello and thank you all in advance,

**Situation:**

I had set up a home file server using Kubuntu, then I decided to switch to Budgie because I liked the experience a bit more... so finally I decided, after some much wresting to give it a rest and just go with Ubuntu server--fairly comfortable with Command Line and would like to learn anyway...

**Question:**

How do I move my drives from my backup drive to my primary drive. My backup drive is a 2 TB surveillance drive that I was only using for temporary storage until I could get SAMBA running on Ubuntu Server (only took like 5 minutes.)

**Extra Info:**

My primary drive is a RAID 5 drive (not that that is important;) it is mounted at "/mnt/Home Storage #1". I used mkfs.ntfs for its partition then mounted it there. (it is primarily for windows computers--I use no other Linux computers)

My secondary drive is mounted at /mnt/old_backup (it is also for windows.)

There is a size difference of about 600 GB of storage space totale, however there are only about 300 GB worth of files that are going to be moved, so there is a little over a TB free after the move on the second drive, so size is not issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not use NTFS for a drive used only on a Linux machine. Use EXT4, btrfs, XFS or some other file system made for Unix. NTFS is a good file system - for Windows. The Linux support is not perfect, and many features desirable in a Unix FS is not in place either in the FS or in the Linux implementation. First thing you should do is to change the file system.
2. Do not mount a filesystem at a directory with spaces or special characters. Sure, it works, if you *consistently know what you're doing*. But chances is that you'll spend time figuring out why it doesn't work because you forgot to escape that special character in some config or similar.
3. For 300GB, it will take a 1-2 hours to copy the data. Simply use `sudo cp -arv /mnt/old_backup/* /mnt/Home\ Storage\ \#1` and watch it finish.

Comment: Should be `/mnt/Home\ Storage\ #1`

Comment: Actually, it is for primarily windows computers. I will add that.

I was aware of that already about, I love that you did express concern on that.

On that note, THANK YOU for the command. I will let you know how it went when it is done. If it works, I will accept this answer.

Comment: If it's served via samba the file system is still for Linux. Use a Unix fs, not NTFS. NTFS support is not perfect, and you're likely to run into issues.

Comment: @vidarlo Interesting, I didn't know that windows could read and write to ext4. Thanks for that heads up. I shall change that. Interesting, I am having an issue, it saying that there is too little space on the drive... I shall shrink the partition on the second drive.

Comment: They can't. But the windows computers will access it via the smb protocol, and doesn't need to understand the underlying file system.

Comment: @vidarlo TRUE! I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: @mook765 And I perfectly illustrated my points about pathnames! :D

Comment: @vidarlo Yes, and you are totally right with that, I just wanted to mention the typo. I didn't want to edit your answer as I wasn't sure if the `#` has to be escaped too.

Comment: @vidarlo UPDATE: It worked, thank you.

I opted to just reinstall Ubuntu SRV--I ended up only making two partitions--a 32 GB swap (the server has only 16GB ECC RAM) and the rest of the like 1.46 TB as the root file.

Also, I opted to take your advice and I simply renamed the mounts to:


/mnt/backup

and

/mnt/home_srv

Learning little-by-little.